# Documenting multiple data objects with roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am writing an R package that contains a data set to be loaded by, say, `data(temp)`. I am using roxygen2 for documentation. In my `data/` directory there is a single file `temp.rda` which contains multiple objects, so `data(temp)` puts multiple variables `var1`, `var2` ... into the workspace. To document the dataset `temp` I created a file `R/temp.R` that contains the usual roxygen2 dataset documentation (`@docType data`, `@name temp`, as well as a `@format` field with a bulleted list of explanations of `var1`, `var2` etc). `roxygenise()` is successful, the package can be built and installed, and `?temp` works as expected.

Now `R CMD check` throws a warning about the undocumented data sets `var1`, `var2` etc because

```
All user-level objects in a package should have documentation entries.
```

I can resolve this by adding additional documentation blocks to `R/temp.R`, documenting each `var1`, `var2`, etc separately like I did for `temp` above. But all the `var*`'s are already described in the documentation of `temp`. **How should I modify the documentation block of `temp` such that `?var1` simply redirects to `?temp`?**

On a related note: Is it considered bad practice that `data(temp)` loads multiple objects (6 in my case)?

Comment: I wonder if aliasing `var*` would solve this?

Comment: Ha I should RTFM. I had tried `#' @alias var1 var2 ...` but roxygen2 said `unknown tag` so I thought alias doesnt work in data set documentation. Now I realised the correct tag is alias**es**, so I have to put `@aliases var1 var2 ...` and everything works. Thanks.

Comment: I had identical error but different cause. I was documenting file name, not the objects _in_ that file name... :)